# How to change the default android api the cocos new project command uses?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am just getting started with cocos2dx (mostly targeting android) and when I create my project with the below command.

```
cocos new FooBar -l cpp -p org.startoftext.foobar
```

The android project it generates is for android api-10. This is way old for me and won't allow me to run it on my phone which is running Lollipop.

I have tried running

```
android update project -p . -t android-19
```

is that correct or should/can I specify the api level on the cocos command?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able change the API that uses your project in the next step, after importing project to the Eclipse ADT. Change it in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The update command I posted worked but I also had to update another project which is the cocos library project. I saw some other examples that eluded to this but I am not on the same computer right now so I cant say the exact path.